# How to synchronize two SELECT elements

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how to synchronize the values and text of two  elements. For instance,

```
<select id="box1" onchange="sync();">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="box2">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

and then sync(); would look something like....

```
function sync()
{
box2.selected = box1.selected;
}
```

Any idea how I would do this?
Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: Why would you do that? Sounds like a confusion GUI. Maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: Do some research into selectedIndex property. Less work than posting on SO.

Comment: @GolezTrol there probably is a better solution, but i'm using it so that a user can select a "default" value for the select box, and then change it if they see fit (otherwise they'd have to select the 'default' twice, when they could just do it once)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
function sync(el1, el2) {
    // if there is no el1 argument we quit here:
    if (!el1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // caching the value of el1:
        var val = el1.value;

        // caching a reference to the element with
        // with which we should be synchronising values:
        var syncWith = document.getElementById(el2);

        // caching the <option> elements of that <select>:
        var options = syncWith.getElementsByTagName('option');

        // iterating over those <option> elements:
        for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {

            // if the value of the current <option> is equal
            // to the value of the changed <select> element's
            // selected value:
            if (options[i].value == val) {

                // we set the current <option> as
                // as selected:
                options[i].selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

// caching the <select> element whose change event should
// be reacted-to:
var selectToSync = document.getElementById('box1');

// binding the onchange event using an anonymous function:
selectToSync.onchange = function(){

    // calling the function:
    sync(this,'box2');
};
```

```js
function sync(el1, el2) {
  if (!el1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    var val = el1.value;
    var syncWith = document.getElementById(el2);
    var options = syncWith.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0, len = options.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (options[i].value == val) {
        options[i].selected = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

var selectToSync = document.getElementById('box1');
selectToSync.onchange = function() {
  sync(this, 'box2');
};
```

```html
<select id="box1">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="box2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sgz4V/).

Or, revised and updated somewhat:

```
function sync() {

  // caching the changed element:
  let el = this;

  // retrieving the id of the element we should synchronise with
  // from the changed-element's data-syncwith custom attribute,
  // using document.getElementById() to retrieve that that element.
  document.getElementById( el.dataset.syncwith )
    // retrieving the <options of that element
    // and finding the <option> at the same index
    // as changed-element's selectedIndex (the index
    // of the selected <option> amongst the options
    // collection) and setting that <option> element's
    // selected property to true:
    .options[ el.selectedIndex ].selected = true;
}

// retrieving the element whose changes should be
// synchronised with another element:
var selectToSync = document.getElementById('box1');

// binding the snyc() function as the change event-handler:
selectToSync.addEventListener('change', sync);
```

```js
function sync() {
  let el = this;
  document.getElementById(el.dataset.syncwith).options[el.selectedIndex].selected = true;
}

var selectToSync = document.getElementById('box1');
selectToSync.addEventListener('change', sync);
```

```html
<select id="box1" data-syncwith="box2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="box2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sgz4V/34/).

Note that this approach does assume – and *requires* – that the `<option>` elements are in the same order.

To update the original approach, where the order is irrelevant, using ES6 approaches (and the same `data-syncwith` custom attribute approach):

```
function sync() {
  // caching the changed element (since
  // we're using it twice):
  let el = this;

  // retrieving the id of the element to synchronise 'to' from 
  // the 'data-syncwith' custom attribute of the changed element,
  // and retrieving its <option> elements. Converting that
  // Array-like collection into an Array using Array.from():
  Array.from(document.getElementById(el.dataset.syncwith).options)
    // Iterating over the array of options using
    // Array.prototype.forEach(), and using an Arrow function to
    // pass the current <otpion> (as 'opt') setting that current
    // <option> element's selected property according to Boolean
    // returned by assessing whether the current option's value
    // is (exactly) equal to the value of the changed element:
    .forEach(opt => opt.selected = opt.value === el.value);
}

var selectToSync = document.getElementById('box1');
selectToSync.addEventListener('change', sync);
```

```js
function sync() {
  let el = this;
  Array.from(document.getElementById(el.dataset.syncwith).options).forEach(opt => opt.selected = opt.value === el.value);
}

let selectToSync = document.getElementById('box1');
selectToSync.addEventListener('change', sync);
```

```html
<select id="box1" data-syncwith="box2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="box2">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sgz4V/36/).

If you look at the HTML in the Snippet you'll see that I switched the positions of `<option>` elements in the second `<select>` element to demonstrate that the `<option>` position doesn't matter in this latter approach.

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).
- [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).
- [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
- [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Answer (score 2):

In the Actual browsers you dont have to do to much...

```
<select id="box1" onchange="box2.value=this.value;">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="box2">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

[Jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/24NMr/)

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery:

```
for (var i=0; i<document.getElementById('box1').options.length; i++)
  if (document.getElementById('box1').options[i].selected)
     for (var j=0; j<document.getElementById('box2').options.length; j++)
        if (document.getElementById('box1').options[i].value == document.getElementById('box2').options[j].value)
          document.getElementById('box2').options[j].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

**With jQuery:**

**Note:** [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) requires `jQuery` > `1.7`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#first').on('change', function() {
    var sel = $('option:selected', this).val();
    $('#second option').filter(function(index, el) {
      return el.value == sel;
    }).prop('selected', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<select name="first" id="first" autocomplete="off">
  <option value="0">-- Select one option --</option>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
  <option value="5">Fifth</option>
  <option value="6">Sixth</option>
</select>

<select name="second" id="second" autocomplete="off">
  <option value="0">-- Select one option --</option>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
  <option value="5">Fifth</option>
  <option value="6">Sixth</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```